# replaceAll "/" with File.separator

Tags: java, regex, separator

In Java, when I do:

```
    "a/b/c/d".replaceAll("/", "@");
```

I get back

```
    a@b@c@d
```

But when I do:

```
    "a/b/c/d".replaceAll("/", File.separator);
```

It throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, and I don't know why. I tried looking this up, but it wasn't very helpful.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It runs fine for me. `a@b@c@d` and `a/b/c/d`.

Comment: Even when you try to replace the forward slashes with a File.separator?

Comment: `File.separator` is a "/" for me! Oh, when I change it to "\\", it does what you said.

Comment: Just for fun you might try just creating a File object with your string as-is and then print out it's path. This may not work but I think on Windows systems it converts / to \ for you. May not always work, but if it did it seems like a more "Legit" way to do it. For example new File("c:/a/b/c").toPath() should return "c:\a\b\c".  I do this all the time so I don't have to quote \ in windows strings.

Comment: Strictly speaking in Java you should use String#replace instead of String#replaceAll. Both replace *all* occurrences but the latter is supposed to be used with regular expressions.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It says it right there in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`.

And, in `Matcher.replaceAll`:

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and **backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.**

What you need to do is to escape any escape characters you have in the replacement string, such as with [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a/b/c/d";
        String sep = "\\"; // File.separator;
        s = s.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Note, I'm using the literal `\\` in `sep` rather than using `File.separator` directly since my separator is the UNIX one - you should be able to just use:

```
s = s.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator));
```

This outputs:

```
a\b\c\d
```

as expected.

Comment: +1, and all he needs now is `Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator)`

Answer (score 10):

Try This

```
    String str = "a/b/c/d";
    str = str.replace("/", File.separator);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I wonder why replaceAll throws an exception? I'll go ahead and accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I just tried this. I didnt evaluated why its throwing exception while using replaceAll method. I will investigate and try to find correct answer in my free time.

Comment: @smit Refer to iccethedral's answer for the explanation.  `replaceAll` parses parameters as regex.

Comment: Yes the explanation given by iccthedral is true. replaceAll method pass the parameter as regex and it treat that parameter completely different (specially for backslashes "\" and dollar signs "$"). If you take a look for java documentation you will get clear idea for replace and replaceAll methods.

Answer (score 9):

`File.separator` is `\` on Windows, that is; it is an escaped backslash. 
However, in a replacement string, it means something [completely different](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29). So you'd have to escape it twice, once for Java, and once for replacement string.

This should work:

```
"a/b/c/d".replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement(File.separator));
```

Comment: With this approach, it will fail on forwardslash separator OS's.  However, the idea is right; you just need to implement it correctly.

Comment: @Vulcan, that's true. I just tried to briefly explain why it happens.

Comment: It will work for Windows but it is not general enough for other OSs

Comment: Actually, my bad, that code isn't valid.  I'm going blank, but there's some escape-related method from Pattern which is necessary here.

Comment: `Pattern.quote` but that won't work either, the result will be `aQ\EbQ\EcQ\Ed`

Comment: @Esailija Ah, I've had a long day.  You're right.  iccthedral Just remove the code, since your explanation deserves a +1

Comment: @Vulcan well it's only kinda right :P, the second argument to `.replaceAll` is not a regex but a replacement expression, where `$` and backslash are special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `str.replace('/', File.separatorChar)`

Comment: What is the benefit of doing it like that instead of this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714791/6648326 ?