# Remove special symbols/seperator e.g. point, comma, - , out of int

Tags: java, user-interface, symbols

I want the person to let write in the date of his/her birthday, after that I want to compare it with the number of pi. 
But I want the program to be flexible. So the date should not just be like 
daymonthyear (13091975) but also like day.month.year (13.09.1975) or like day-month-year (13-09-1975)
I already found a idea but it does not work

```
String sep = "";
String geb = nf_datum.getText();
geb = geb.replaceAll(".", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep));
```

i have found this idea with "replaceAll" here: [replaceAll "/" with File.separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714722/replaceall-with-file-separator)
I hope somebody can help me??

Comment: I am not shure how you the question mean :D but It is a gui and nf_datum is the number field, later I put the numbers into a array

Comment: what is your java version? can you use java 8?

Comment: When you say "it does not work" - in what way does it not work? Do you get an error, or just not the output you are expecting? In general, trying to write your own code to handle date parsing and formatting logic is a very bad idea; Java has many different utilities built-in to do the hard work for you. I suggest you have a look at the documentation, starting [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateintro.html), to see what Java will give you for free.

Comment: First: I did not get an error, I got an output I did not expect. Second: It makes sense to use the utilities of java, but as I understood they give the current date out? I want to let them write their birthday :(

Answer (score 0):

Using java8 you can get that string and define a **DateTimeFormatter**, this will give you the flexibility to parse a string into a LocalDate and you dont need to take care how the string "looks like", after that you will get a LocalDate object from which you can get the year, month and day

```
String geburtstag = "-";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("[ddMMyyyy]" + "[ddMMyyyy]" + "[dd.MM.yyyy]" + "[dd-MM-yyyy]");
// case1
geburtstag = "23.06.2017";
LocalDate ldt = LocalDate.parse(geburtstag, formatter);
System.out.println("Year: " + ldt.getYear());
System.out.println("Month: " + ldt.getMonthValue());
System.out.println("Day: " + ldt.getDayOfMonth());
// case2
geburtstag = "23062017";
ldt = LocalDate.parse(geburtstag, formatter);
System.out.println("Year: " + ldt.getYear());
System.out.println("Month: " + ldt.getMonthValue());
System.out.println("Day: " + ldt.getDayOfMonth());
// case3
geburtstag = "23-06-2017";
ldt = LocalDate.parse(geburtstag, formatter);
System.out.println("Year: " + ldt.getYear());
System.out.println("Month: " + ldt.getMonthValue());
System.out.println("Day: " + ldt.getDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: to be honest I do not understand yours at all (not even the beginning):(

Comment: which part @Jana?

Comment: at the beginning you defined the DateTimeFormatter, right? What is meant whit .of Pattern? I do not know what the instruction mean or does. And then you converted the LocalDate with parse in what? (Because ddMMyyyy is ok, and I need the dates in this way. So I just wanted to convert the date, if it is in another way written.)

Comment: ***parse*** converts into a  locadate any given string with those formats defined in **formatter**....